# How do I fork process to return data using php and pcntl functions?

Tags: php, pcntl

What I want to achieve is fork the process and in the child process do a webservice/database query and when the data returns to the child process I need to display it on the page.  I have a few questions regarding this.

How do I get the returned data back to the script that invoked the fork process?

How would I be able to poll to see if any results have returned?  Would this just simply be a case of setting a boolean variable to true in the parent process after the child has returned and somehow check for that?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
  // this script invokes the fork process from the web as it cannot be invoked directly from the web.
  $testvar='testvalue';
 shell_exec("/usr/bin/php5 /var/www/public_html/fork.php '?testvar=".$testvar."' &");
?>


<?php  // this script does the forking
    $pid = pcntl_fork(); 
    echo "\npid: ".$pid;
    if ($pid == -1) { 
       die("could not fork"); 
    } elseif ($pid) { 
        echo "\nI'm the Parent (".$pid.") "; 
        pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status, WUNTRACED);
        echo "\nchild process returned"; 
    } else { 
        /*
            Do webservice / database query here
        */
       echo "\nI am the child - sleeping for 20 secs"; 
        sleep(20); 
       echo "\nreturning to parent now \n\n\n"; 
    } 

    exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: Did you take a look at using Shared Memory? Full documentation can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php

Comment: I'll take a look at that.  I've used this method before a few years ago, just can't remember exactly how it was done.

Comment: @SanderBackus that looks useful.  Any idea how I would forward the user to to a "searching for results" page which polls for 30secs or so then shows the results when they return?  I would need to pass the semaphore ID to the "searching" script which checks the semaphore periodically.  I'm a bit stumped right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a more simpler ans (hopefully) straight forward sample on how to do it:

```php
<?php

echo '<pre>P: '.getmypid().' is the thread before fork'.PHP_EOL;
$pid = pcntl_fork();
 
if($pid == -1) {
  die('could not fork'.PHP_EOL);
} 

if ($pid === 0) {
    sleep(2);
    file_put_contents('php://stdout', PHP_EOL.'----------------> REQUEST_METHOD (will show on logs - it inherits parent\'s environment): '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].PHP_EOL);
    file_put_contents('php://stdout', PHP_EOL.'----------------> C: '.getmypid().' is the thread of the child'.PHP_EOL);
    file_put_contents('php://stdout', PHP_EOL.'----------------> P: '.posix_getppid().' is the threaded parent (myself)'.PHP_EOL);
    file_put_contents('php://stdout', $content);
    file_put_contents('php://stdout', $content);
    sleep(5);
    file_put_contents('php://stdout', PHP_EOL.'----------------> C: '.getmypid().' is the thread after sleep'.PHP_EOL);
    exit();
}

echo 'REQUEST_METHOD (will show on client\'s web server response - have original environment): '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].PHP_EOL;
echo 'P: '.getmypid().' is the threaded parent'.PHP_EOL;
echo 'C: '.$pid.' is the thread of the child'.PHP_EOL;

exit();
```